# How to disable an arrow using java script of a carousel

Tags: image, javascript

I want to disable this img tag where id is scroll_disable how to achieve this using java script. this image is a arrow key of a carousel of a live shopping website what i want to do is when there is no images for this product i want to disable this arrow.so that user can not scroll further. i need solution in java script only.can i do this onclick() function?

```
<div id="btn-next" class="f-x3" style="position:relative; float:left;   width:30px;height:50px; padding-left:10px; padding-top:20px; overflow:visible">
<p class="f-lp"  ><a  href="#" class="carousel_carousel next" ><img src="/site/images /arrows1.jpeg" border="0" width="21" height="24" style="vertical-align:baseline" id="scroll_disable"  /></a></p>
</div>
```

how to write java script for this?

Comment: reduce the opacity of image so that it looks like as disabled. And make sure that onclick or any other event doesn't do any thing (i.e. don't perform any activity).

Answer (score 0):

Okay, first of all, when you're writing in a language that is not your first, punctuation gets extra-important.

If you don't have to worry about images showing up in the carousel later, try this:

```
document.getElementById('btn-next').removeEventListener('click');
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out the following.

http://jsfiddle.net/WRbxe

`<img>` is not a form element and hence can't be disabled. However if you use `<input type="image">` it can be disabled using,

```
document.getElementById('scroll_disable').disabled=true;
```